# Parameterised SQL WHERE statement and SAS Macro Language problems

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I have a piece of code that has parameterised a hundred or so similar, but not identical SQL statements I need to generate data I require. The parameterisation works fine apart from the where statements. I am passing in a macro string of the following format:

```
where PERIOD_LAST_DTTM = '31DEC2017:23:59:59'dt
  and myvar1 = 1 and myvar2 < 0
  and myvar3 in ('SOME STRING', 'SOME OTHER STRING')
```

...with the following syntax:

```
%if %eval(&inn_sel_var. ^= &comp_var2.) %then %do;

        &inn_sel_var.

%end;
```

/*&inn_sel_var is where string &comp_var2 = NULL*/

...but am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       where PERIOD_LAST_DTTM = '31DEC2017:23:59:59'dt and myvar1 = 1 and myvar2 < 0 and myvar3 in ('SOME STRING', 'SOME OTHER STRING')                                                                                    


             ^= NULL 
ERROR: %EVAL function has no expression to evaluate, or %IF statement has no condition.
ERROR: The macro MODEL_CHECKS will stop executing.
```

...I have tried using %STR, %SUPERQ, %QUOTE, %BQUOTE, %NRQUOTE, %NRBQUOTE and %UNQUOTE, but I keep on hitting errors. Could someone please advise what I need to do in order for feed my parameterised where statements in correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Debugging macro problems of this nature require a good understanding of the macro variables in play.  Can you post some of the log when `options mtrace mprint;` are on ? Also, %if does an implicit %eval, does the same error happen if you remove only the token $eval ?  Can you show the macro declaration and invocation ?  Can you show the actual tries made with the macro quoting functions within the macro declarations and the macro invocation ?

Comment: Why would those two macro variable have the same value when one of them contains a WHERE statement/clause?  Are you just trying to test if the two where clauses are using the exact same characters?

Comment: Use `options mlogic symbolgen` to see more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show more of your program and/or log.

But using `%superq()` should prevent that type of error message in your `%IF` statement.

```
%if %superq(inn_sel_var) ne %superq(comp_var2) %then &inn_sel_var. ;
```

Of course the value of the `INN_SEL_VAR` macro variable might still generate errors in the generated SAS code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Ok, this seems to work now. I was using an ampersand at the start of my macro variable referenced within the %superq and you are not. I am not really sure why/how not using the ampersands here will work...

Comment: `%superq()` takes the NAME of the macro variable to quote. You would only use an `&` if you have a macro variable that contains the name of the macro variable you want to quote.

Comment: ok. can %superq mask errors in the log? I am getting a red 'x' in my EG session suggesting an error has occured, but cannot see 'ERROR:' or any red underlined text in the log.

Comment: Macro quoting mishaps can cause a lot of havoc with a SAS session.  Reinitialize your SAS sessions, or if you can't figure out how to do that restart EG.